# How can i use Fiddler to debug Web API Post and Put methods in a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have been playing with Asp.Net Web API in Visual Studio 2012. I have 2 classes, Continent, which then has a collection of Countries. I can easily debug continent Post and Put methods. But i can't seem to find a way to assign Continent to a Country object when i create it.

Does anyone know how to debug Web API Post and Put methods in a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship? Every option i have tried up to this point, gives me an error that:

eg: `{"Name":"Canada1","Continent":"1"}` says;

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**NOTE:** I will also take suggestions to a different Web Debugger you are familiar with as long as it works the in situation described.

Answer (score 1):

What your data relationship is, has no concerns in relation to Web Api, Fiddler, etc.
Best way is to have your specific controllers for each entity type and use simple view models to transport data in the form of JSON. It is possible though to create a view models, in your case, Continent model, that contains collection of Countries. In JSON it will be represented as collection/array. Now, how you populate the model in your controller/business object - doesn't matter.

Using Fiddler is the same as for simple models. You will need to provide JSON which has Continent properties and Collection of countries with their properties. Make sure to setup content type in headers and it should work fine. It worked for me, like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, i see what you mean and i will try it. But lets say, there are Continent objects already created. When i am creating Country objects, how would i assign Continent to them? See the example in the post they way i have been trying to achieve this.

Comment: When you create country, you fill ID of the continent, which was selected when you clicked "new country" into country model/JSON. If it works other way around, you assign continent to a country, you got to select Id from a list of continents, or something else . And just fill that Id into model of a country. In many-to-many, your controller may need to have something like this `PostAssignContToCountry(int contId, int countryId)`. Or if create new + assign in one step then `PostAssignContToNewCountry(int contId, CountryModel country)`

Comment: That i know how to do, what i was asking was, how can i write up a json data to post as a country object in fiddler? This is a plain web api and i haven't written a client yet

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/Making-Web-APIs-with-ASP.NET-MVC-4-Beta_BEA5/image_12.png

Comment: The picture is actually on this page http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx